# Error splicing file: Value too large for defined data type

Tags: partitioning, backup, ntfs, external-hdd

I just bought a new external hard disk for backup. When copying some files I get this error:

> Error splicing file: Value too large for defined data type

I have searched for this but can't find anything relevant. I am copying from a NTFS partition on my Ubuntu to another NTFS partition on the external hdd. There error pops up only for some files no matter the size.

Are the files corrupted or encrypted or is it just bad NTFS? Also I am using Ubuntu 10.4. And the partitions are writable via NTFS config tool.

Comment: You're doing it via directly connected drives or samba?  Bug discussed here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=85999 was over samba

Comment: How big are the files? I had this problem once with 4GB ISO files. I had to split my files down into smaller parts before I copied them over.

Answer (score 1):

From the original [bug #455122](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/455122) on Launchpad, when mounting the share add `,nounix,noserverino` to the options, i.e.:

```
mount -t cifs -o user=me,pass=secret,nounix,noserverino //server/share /mount
```